# Gnuplot is not ploting anymore

Tags: gnuplot

I have a script to plot a graph with gnuplot. Last manth this script was ploting with no errors. I didn't make any modification but now it is not ploting anymore. I did all steps on this web site but still don't work. http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00092000000000000000

Does anybody have an idea of what is happening?
Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

reset

set grid
set title 'Desempenho do BTRIM com peers de reputação condicionada'
set xlabel 'Tempo'
set ylabel 'Vazão - downloads completos / tempo'
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 3 lc rgb '#29c524' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 4 lc rgb '#7D72F9' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set style line 5 lc rgb '#000000' lt 1 lw 2 pi -1 ps 1.0
set pointintervalbox 0

plot '<paste ../00/Statistic100.txt ../01/Statistic100.txt ../02/Statistic100.txt ../03/Statistic100.txt ../04/Statistic100.txt ../05/Statistic100.txt ../06/Statistic100.txt ../07/Statistic100.txt ../08/Statistic100.txt ../09/Statistic100.txt' smooth unique with linespoint lt 5 lw 1 title 'Reputação de 100%', \
'<paste ../00/Statistic75.txt ../01/Statistic75.txt ../02/Statistic75.txt ../03/Statistic75.txt ../04/Statistic75.txt ../05/Statistic75.txt ../06/Statistic75.txt ../07/Statistic75.txt ../08/Statistic75.txt ../09/Statistic75.txt' smooth unique with linespoint lt 6 lw 1 title 'Reputação de 75%', \
'<paste ../00/Statistic50.txt ../01/Statistic50.txt ../02/Statistic50.txt ../03/Statistic50.txt ../04/Statistic50.txt ../05/Statistic50.txt ../06/Statistic50.txt ../07/Statistic50.txt ../08/Statistic50.txt ../09/Statistic50.txt' smooth unique with linespoint lt 7 lw 1 title 'Reputação de 50%', \
'<paste ../00/Statistic25.txt ../01/Statistic25.txt ../02/Statistic25.txt ../03/Statistic25.txt ../04/Statistic25.txt ../05/Statistic25.txt ../06/Statistic25.txt ../07/Statistic25.txt ../08/Statistic25.txt ../09/Statistic25.txt' smooth unique with linespoint lt 8 lw 1 title 'Reputação de 25%'

pause -1
```

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. Gnuplot version? Terminal (wxt, qt, x11, ...)? Check `show terminal`. What means 'not plotting'? Does a window open? Does e.g. `set terminal postscript` work? Does it work with a simple `plot x; pause -1` in the file? etc.

Comment: probably also worth checking if all the paste commands work on their own and to check the input files, perhaps there is a some mix of text and numbers or a character gnuplot can't parse as a number in it?